# .htaccess login form dynamic url to static

Tags: .htaccess

my login form url is like `www.website.com/form/index.php` , and I made the url looks clean `www.website.com/form/`. Once logged in, the page will redirect the page to `www.website.com/form/content.php`, and also I have another page `www.website.com/form/morefiles.php`

how can I make everything just to stay the url `www.website.com/form/`

seems doesn't work

```
RewriteRule ^form\.php$ /^form\ [L]
```

Comment: You can't have one clean URI pointing to three different existing scripts. It cannot do the guess work for you. Nonetheless, you could use RewriteMap for silently mapping the `content.php`.

Answer (score 0):

As commented by @Mike above you cannot have one clean URI `/form/` pointing to 3 URIs. What you can probably do is (with code changes) is inside `/form/index.php`:

1. include `/form/content.php` after login is successful (instead of redirection)
2. Finally include `/form/morefiles.php`